# Clarification required regarding spark scala Array()

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scala-collections

Say, I have a dataframe. Few of the column values in that dataframe is Array() i.e., Array[Nothing]. How can i filter these? because if i don't it will throw error if someone tries to print the dataframe or so.

Comment: you can also use `size` function i.e: `df.where("size(ar) > 0")`. More info here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#size

Comment: `Àrray[Nothing]` cannot be a type of a column (Note that `Ǹothing` is an actual type in scala)

Comment: an empty Array should not throw error in Spark Scala, please clarify

Answer (score 1):

Just filter the empty array.

```
val df1 = df.withColumn("array", array())
df1.show()

+---+-----+
| id|array|
+---+-----+
|  1|   []|
+---+-----+

val df2 = df1.filter("array != array()")
df2.show()

+---+-----+
| id|array|
+---+-----+
+---+-----+
```